# Why did C++11 remove the default value from the prototypes of std::vector's fill constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In C++98 the prototype for `std::vector`'s fill constructor has a default value for the initializer.

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

C++11 uses two prototypes.

```
explicit vector (size_type n);
         vector (size_type n, const value_type& val,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

(In C++14 the fill constructor changed again, but it's not the point of this question.)

A reference link is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Why did C++11 deprecate the default initializer value `value_type()`?

By the way, I tried to compile the following code with `clang++ -std=c++11` and it issued an error, which means the value type still needs to have a default constructor like `S() {}`, i.e. be default-constructible.

```
#include <vector>

struct S {
    int k;
    S(int k) : k(k) {} // intentionally remove the synthesized default constructor
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> s(5); // error: no matching constructor
}
```

Comment: The example you show at the end wouldn't have worked prior to C++11 either because `S` is not default constructible. And C++11 didn't *deprecate* the default value, that single constructor was replaced by two others.

Comment: Default values are evil.

Comment: @Praetorian yeah I should've said C++11 *removed* the default value from the constructor's prototypes.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  you'll have to elaborate

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The C++98 took a prototype object, then copied it n times.  By default the prototype was a default-constructed object.

The C++11 version constructs n default-constructed objects.

This eliminates n copies and replaces it with n default-constructions.  In addition, it avoids constructing the prototype.

Suppose your class looks like this:

```
struct bulky {
  std::vector<int> v;
  bulky():v(1000) {} // 1000 ints
  bulky(bulky const&)=default;
  bulky& operator=(bulky const&)=default;

  // in C++11, avoid ever having an empty vector to maintain
  // invariants:
  bulky(bulky&& o):bulky() {
    std::swap(v, o.v);
  }
  bulky& operator=(bulky&& o) {
    std::swap(v,o.v);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

this is a class that *always* owns a buffer of `1000` `int`s.

if we then create a vector of `bulky`:

```
std::vector<bulky> v(2);
```

in C++98 this allocated 3 times 1000 integers.  In C++11 this allocated only 2 times 1000 integers.

In addition, the C++98 version requires that the type be copyable.  There are non-copyable types in C++11, such as `std::unique_ptr<T>`, and a `vector` of default-constructed unique pointers cannot be generated using the C++98 signature.  The C++11 signature has no problem with it.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(100);
```

The above wouldn't work if we still had the C++98 version.

Comment: I would probably revert the explanation, as correctness trumps efficiency :D But nevertheless, a good answer to the good question.

Comment: @SergeyA I am uncertain when exactly the requirements for being in a vector where relaxed from being on the type passed to vector, and instead coupled to the exact methods used.  The efficiency difference certainly appeared in C++11; I am uncertain if technically the relaxed requirement did.  So I detailed exactly what I knew, and then mentioned that somewhere in C++11/14 it also led to relaxed requirements on a type (in practice in C++11, I am uncertain if the standard actually relaxed it before C++14, because I don't remember)

Comment: nice explanation, i just dont understand why in the c++98 version the prototype object isnt used as the first element (ie that would also make only 2000 integers allocated in your example)

Comment: @tobi303 The prototype exists on the stack, in the argument.  The objects exist in memory managed by the vector.  The vector does not manage the argument, so it cannot be the first object in the vector.  C++ has value semantics, that object has a definite location.  In C++11 they could have made it both an rvalue or lvalue argument and move from it, but my insane `bulky` type refuses to ever be empty even when moved-from so it wouldn't help either.

Comment: @Yakk, I see what you mean. Makes sense.

Comment: @Yakk yeah makes sense, I was so much focused on the case where no parameter is passed and the default `value_type()` is used and forgot that it is a parameter

Comment: @Yakk it was relaxed in C++11.  The `explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(),
const Allocator& = Allocator());` from C++98 was split into two `explicit vector(size_type n);
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());`.  Basically, in C++98 the only way to put elements into a vector was to copy them.

Answer (score 47):

The reason the constructor was split in two was to support "move-only" types such as `unique_ptr<T>`.

This constructor:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

requires `T` to be copy constructible, because `n` `T`s must be copied from `value` to populate the `vector`.

This constructor:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

does *not* require `T` to be copy constructible, only default constructible.

The latter constructor works with `unique_ptr<T>`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> s(5);
```

while the former constructor does not.

Here is the proposal that made this change:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1858.html#23.2.4.1%20-%20vector%20constructors,%20copy,%20and%20assignment

And this paper has some of the rationale, though is admittedly a little on the terse side:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1771.html

Fwiw, `resize`:

```
void resize(size_type sz, T c = T());
```

was split into:

```
void resize(size_type sz);
void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

for the exact same reason.  The first requires default constructible but not copy constructible (to support default constructible move-only types), and the second requires copy constructible.

These changes were not 100% backwards compatible.  For some types (e.g. reference counted smart pointers), copy constructing from a default constructed object is not the same as default construction.  However the benefit of supporting move-only types was judged to be worth the cost of this API breakage.

Comment: Good point. `unique_ptr<T>` is an excellent example of non-copiable class. Unfortunately there can only be one accepted answer.

Comment: This seems like the real answer since it explains *why* it was done. (Yakk's currently accepted answer mentions it too, but briefly as an aside.)

Comment: Couldn't they just `enable_if` `is_copy_constructible`?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  That could've been done.  I judged that the C++11 behavior of `container<T>(n)` was actually often preferable, and if the C++98 behavior was actually desired, then that was still available with the syntax `container<T>(n, T{})`.  And in the vast majority of cases there is no semantic difference (most use cases wouldn't the change).  There was some risk, but there was greater benefit.  In hindsight, I think the gamble worked.